# What do -fsanitize=function (UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer) errors actually mean?

Tags: clang, llvm, function-pointers

When compiling MAME/MESS (https://github.com/mamedev/mame/) with clang 3.5 on ubuntu 14.04 with -fsanitize=function I am getting lots of the following errors:

```
src/lib/util/delegate.h:651:64: runtime error: call to function osd_file_output_callback(_IO_FILE*, char const*, __va_list_tag*) through pointer to incorrect function type 'void (*)(delegate_generic_class *, const char *, __va_list_tag *)'
/home/notroot/trunk/src/osd/osdcore.c:14: note: osd_file_output_callback(_IO_FILE*, char const*, __va_list_tag*) defined here

src/lib/util/delegate.h:649:42: runtime error: call to function rom_exit(running_machine&) through pointer to incorrect function type 'void (*)(delegate_generic_class *)'
/home/notroot/trunk/src/emu/romload.c:1514: note: rom_exit(running_machine&) defined here
```

I don't really understand what these errors mean since if the function signature doesn't match I would expect the application to just crash at some point. So far nobody could explain to me what this error actually means or why this is working.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't really understand what these errors mean since if the function signature doesn't match I would expect the application to just crash at some point.

And that's the danger of undefined behaviour. It does mean that the function signature doesn't match. It doesn't mean it will crash, or wait until the boss it looking before crashing, or corrupt the stack or whatnot. It could even turn out to be completely unobservable today, but not with a future version of the compiler (or an older version). Undefined behaviour is like that. You can not draw conclusions about the absence of undefined behaviour from the observed behaviour.

In your case, it isn't crashing because pointer-to-_IO_FILE and pointer-to-delegate_generic_class are the same size and there's nothing special about them in the ABI (assuming x86-64 linux).

Comment: Ah, so this warning is about enforcing "type safety" in the function signature, which is not necessary as long as the size of them matches. I get it now - makes sense.